# How to implement ajax voting application using the Grails Framework?

Tags: jquery, grails, prototype, grails-plugin, voting

any good samples of code or articles that can help?

Comment: What are you asking for exactly? It's prety specific to ask for how to implement a particular kind of application in a particular programming language/framework. What are you having difficulty with? You want to start with the design of your application and worry about the implmentation after you have the basics set (probably on paper).

Comment: I want to implement ajax voting similar to stackoverflow voting up&down arrows

Comment: should I use JQuery or Prototype, both got plugins but I can't find a plugin similar to stackoverflow. I was hoping that someone with more experience point out something good

Comment: its possible to have both if you need both, but either works fine. jquery seems to do better at dom manipulation than prototype.

Answer (score 0):

There isnt a plugin that can do "voting", because voting is quite domain specific.

It would be easy to implement a simple voting app in grails. I'd write it here, but I'd need more details as to what you are voting for, who votes etc.

As for the ajax part, that is orthogonal to voting. to implement "ajax" in your app, simply use the remoteFunction tag : http://www.grails.org/Tag+-+remoteFunction for some documentation. or you can roll your own using jquery.

Comment: I am thinking Q&A voting example containing 4 Domain Classes: Question.groovy Answer.groovy Vote.groovy Person.groovy

How can I implement it and use ajax library(JQuery or Prototype) in Taglibs?